# Why does my PC have 4 graphics adapters?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I bought a `Fujitsu Lifebook AH532` laptop yesterday. Before buying it, I was told it has a `GeForce GT640` graphics card installed, but when I started it and ran `AIDA64` it showed me 4 graphics adapters, 3 from `Intel` and 1 from `nVidia`.

[image: Video adapters]

I then ran a benchmark in `GTA IV`, and the used graphics device was `Intel's`, not the `nVidia`.

What does it mean to have 4 adapters, and how do they function?

Comment: Which laptop model ?

Comment: Fujitsu Lifebook AH532

Comment: Its simple. Because there are 4 ports. 3 are managed by the Indel HD Graphics 4000 and last one handled by the GeForce GT 6400M. VGA, HDMI, and the XGA HD display. I can't find a specification on the model you have, I found the manual, but makes no reference to the Nvidia card.  Why AIDA64 does this I can't explain, thats a closed source application, but 3 of the 4 can be displayed by the ports so simplest explaination normally is the explaination.  You really only have 2, if you want GTAIV to use your NVidia card you might want to configure your laptop to use that instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What do you mean, 4 ports? So when I'm playing games, are they handled by the Intel HD Graphics, or nVidia GT640?

Comment: @GregaMenih - Depends on the current settings of your laptop.  You have 2 adapters.  AIDA64 is displaying 4 because you have the laptop monitor + 3 additional ports.  Check the specifications on your laptop ( or post them ) to understand what I am talking about.

Comment: @Ramhound are you claiming his laptop has 3 ports (for 3 different monitors)?  you mean sockets right? Can you point to them?   here is a pic.  http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/products/computing/pc/notebooks-tablets/all-round/lifebook-ah532/    I see a few identical sockets there but they are surely USB I doubt they are HDMI 'cos then where would USB be. If you really think there are 3 sockets for monitors, you should be able to point to them. And i'm guessing the owner of the laptop doesn't think so or if he does he hasn't noticed, and that's quite a thing to not notice!

Comment: The laptop only has a VGA and a HDMI port. But I have figured it out. It turns out it's a power saving laptop, so whenever there's no need for a higher performance graphics it uses the Intel HD Graphics, and when I run anything that need better graphics, the nVidia is used. I still don't understand why there are 3 adapters for Intel though.

Comment: @GregaMenih perhaps it's possible there are many versions of the driver installed? I don't know if it'd have that effect though!

Comment: The specifications I found on the laptop indicate it has at least three ports though

Comment: @Ramhound i'm sure they do though can you link to these specifications you keep mentioning?

Comment: @barlop - I simply did a google search and found the manual that indicated what ports the laptop has.

Comment: @Ramhound can you link to it and quote from it. if not then fine.

Comment: @barlop - I already did quote it. You have at least 2 ports + the laptop display. As I indicated the manual said nothing about the GeForce option.  As for linking it, I deleted the manual, 7 days ago.

Comment: @Ramhound you say you quoted it, so can you include quotation marks around your quote so I can see the quote?  my guess is you didn't quote it. or you don't know what quoting something means.

Comment: @barlop - I know exactly what quoting means. I cannot edit my 7 day old comment to add quotation marks. You already linked to the page with the Datasheet so it would be sort of pointless for me to do it. The third port would have been provided by the WiDi support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your laptop has 2 hardware GPU chips - Intel HD Graphics 4000 and the Nvidia GT 6400.

As you pointed out the driver will switch in between based on performance requirements.

What you see in the control panel are all of the virtual instances running. I believe each one is assign to an output:

1x HDMI
1x VGA
1x WiDi (Intel wireless Display for connecting to TVs)